# how to send url from php file to js file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

> php file

```
<?php
   function myfunc()
   {
           //code here
   }
?>
 <script>
 var ur="ajaxc-alling-file.php";
 </script>
 <script src="custom.js"></script>
```

> js file

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
       var geturl=ur;
       alert(geturl);
});
```

> Result  will be display in alert box "ajaxc-alling-file.php"

Comment: Simply `alert(url);` should work!

Comment: You have at least two typos. `var geturl=ur;` and `documnet` You also need to include jQuery

Comment: also the first script block isn't closed `<script>` => `</script>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot send url in a file but can call js function with url in arguments.
for example. in file define a funcrion

```
   //script.js
   function myScriptFunction(url){
      alert(url);
   }
```

include this file in your php file
and in your php file just call funcrion by passing url argument. like.

```
     <script>
         var url = "<?php echo get_url(ID);?>";
         myScriptFunction(url);
     </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var url="ajaxc-alling-file.php";
    alert(url);
});
```